# Migrate complex TypoScript condition to 10 LTS / 11 LTS

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news, typo3-10.x

I try to migrate the following condition without success:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0] || [globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news_preview > 0] && [PIDinRootline = 123, 456]
```

I tried something like this, but none of my attempts seem to work:

```
[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0  || traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news_preview') > 0] && [123 in tree.rootLineIds || 456 in tree.rootLineIds]
```

How do i have to write such complex conditions in Symfony Expression Language/TypoScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write the complete condition into one square brackets expression:

```
[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0 || traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news_preview') > 0] && (123 in tree.rootLineIds || 456 in tree.rootLineIds)]
```

Comment: There is a syntax error... Before `&&` is a closing bracket that is never opened.
But IMO the first two conditions have to be combined in normal brackets, otherwise the part to the right of the '&&' 'would only be linked to the condition directly to the left of it and only the evaluation of the two would be ORed with the foremost part

Comment: Should it look something like this?

```[(traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0 && (123 in tree.rootLineIds || 456 in tree.rootLineIds)) || (traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news_preview') > 0 && (123 in tree.rootLineIds || 456 in tree.rootLineIds))]```